# Creating contact list with sorted names and images from MySQL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

everybody. Right now i'm trying to make an UITableView which have alphabetically sorted contact names and profile picture. Just like this image:[image: Contact list]
The site that provide this image showed me how to make something like this, but i had problem since in my app we don't have static images but using MySQL database to provide the saved contact. I able to grab the data needed via web service and put it in NSDictionary named dataDict. In NSLog, it showed like this:

```
animal={(id="1",name="BEAR",images="bear321.jpg"),(id="2",name="Dog",images="puppy.jpg"),(id="3",name="GOOSE",images="null"),...so on}
```

Since i don't know how to parse the dictionary i have, right now i'm still using this code:-

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    animals = @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"],
                @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
                @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"],
                @"E" : @[@"Emu"],
                @"G" : @[@"Giraffe", @"Greater Rhea"],
                @"H" : @[@"Hippopotamus", @"Horse"],
                @"K" : @[@"Koala"],
                @"L" : @[@"Lion", @"Llama"],
                @"M" : @[@"Manatus", @"Meerkat"],
                @"P" : @[@"Panda", @"Peacock", @"Pig", @"Platypus", @"Polar Bear"],
                @"R" : @[@"Rhinoceros"],
                @"S" : @[@"Seagull"],
                @"T" : @[@"Tasmania Devil"],
                @"W" : @[@"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"]};

    animalSectionTitles = [[animals allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}

- (NSString *)getImageFilename:(NSString *)animal
{
    NSString *imageFilename = [[animal lowercaseString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
    imageFilename = [imageFilename stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];

    return imageFilename;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSString *sectionTitle = [animalSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *sectionAnimals = [animals objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    return [sectionAnimals count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *sectionTitle = [animalSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionAnimals = [animals objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSString *animal = [sectionAnimals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = animal;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self getImageFilename:animal]];

    return cell;
}
```

Exactly the same [like this site](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/) So please help me solve my problem by tell me what i need to modify so i can add picture name and image based on my dynamic dictionary instead of hardcoded like the above. Thanks a lot in advance ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you were trying to do.

```
@interface ViewController ()
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *animals;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *sections;
@end

@implementation ViewController

static NSString *const CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  NSArray *allAnimals = @[@{@"name": @"Bear"}, @{@"name": @"Black Swan"}, @{@"name": @"Buffalo"}, @{@"name": @"Camel"}, @{@"name": @"Cockatoo"}, @{@"name": @"Dog"}, @{@"name": @"Donkey"}, @{@"name": @"Emu"},
    @{@"name": @"Giraffe"},@{@"name":  @"Greater Rhea"}, @{@"name": @"Hippopotamus"}, @{@"name": @"Horse"}, @{@"name": @"Koala"}, @{@"name": @"Lion"}, @{@"name": @"Llama"}, @{@"name": @"Manatus"}, @{@"name": @"Meerkat"}, @{@"name": @"Panda"}, @{@"name": @"Peacock"}, @{@"name": @"Pig"}, @{@"name": @"Platypus"}, @{@"name": @"Polar Bear"}, @{@"name": @"Rhinoceros"}, @{@"name": @"Seagull"}, @{@"name": @"Tasmania Devil"}, @{@"name": @"Whale"}, @{@"name": @"Whale Shark"}, @{@"name": @"Wombat"}];


  UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];


  NSArray *sectionIndexTitles = [collation sectionIndexTitles];

  _animals = [NSMutableArray array];

  for(int i = 0 ; i < sectionIndexTitles.count; i++){
    [self.animals addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
  }

  for(NSDictionary *anAnimal in allAnimals){

    NSString *name = anAnimal[@"name"];

    NSUInteger section = [collation sectionForObject:name collationStringSelector:@selector(capitalizedString)];

    NSMutableArray *array = [self.animals objectAtIndex:section];

    [array addObject:anAnimal];


  }

}

- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

  UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
  if([self.animals[section] count] > 0 ) return [collation sectionIndexTitles][section];
  return 0;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
  UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
  return [[collation sectionIndexTitles] count];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  NSArray *animalsInSection = [self.animals objectAtIndex:section];
  return animalsInSection.count;
}


- (NSArray*)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
  UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation =  [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
  return [collation sectionIndexTitles];
}


- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


  NSArray  *animalsInSection = [self.animals objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
  cell.textLabel.text = animalsInSection[indexPath.row][@"name"];
  return cell;
}

  @end
```

I hope that is what you were trying to do.

Comment: I think this code is far from what i need. First, i don't use this code @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"], @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"]...and so on since what i need is how to make a dictionary that able to make this dictionary animal={(id="1",name="BEAR",images="bear321.jpg"),(id="2",name="Dog",images="puppy.jpg"),(id="3",name="GOOSE",images="null"),...so on} into something like the former. Second, i need an dictionary to grab my images link but still arranged like the name. @insane-36 Thanks for the help anyway, hope you understand what i need :'(

Comment: In that case you could use the same array you get from the response to have the tableview with indexes like that. Do you want me to do it like so.

Comment: Yes, please help me if you can because i don't know how to make it :( @insane-36

Comment: Please see my edit. I suppose you get the response similar to allAnimals which has to be converted to proper sectioned object using UIIndexedCollation and so it is easy.

Comment: This code works if only i had static animals, what if i can create new animals and add new images? Maybe NSMutableArray and addObject function will do the trick for the static array. Until this far i had no problem. But, i also need to show the animals image in the list, just before the name and i don't want a horse have cat's image so, i need the image also sorted. I'm not yet trying your code but it seems it not showing the images yet. @insane-36 what do you think?

Comment: I dont have the images with me. This is the basic idea of the implementation. It places the dictionary of the name or whatever other keys in the same object, so you could download the image or set the image locally.

Comment: I need to use setImageByURL, neither local image or download it. That's why there is an image name in the dictionary. So i just need to put the url like this @"http://imageshack.com/blablabla/%@",image name

Comment: Ok send me the entire content of the dictionary. I will do the entire tableview for you.

Comment: Could you please send message to my email 'edwardwijaya26@gmail.com' so i can send my entire code to you. The dictionary not using static data but dynamically based on database @insane-36